# Android AndEngine analogController

Tags: android, controller, game-physics, andengine

i am new to **AndEngine**,

Can i use standart **analogController** and allow only *horizontal* or *vertical* moving of it ?

I undestand that i can use this controller to draw my own only with X\Y coordinate, but i am interesting if there is standart functionality to make such horizontal\vertical controller ? (**not** only ignore one of the axis but restrict moving on it)

Thx for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to make HorizontalAnalogScreenController from BaseController and AnalogController: super.onUpdateControlKnob(pRelativeX, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Use DigitalOnScreenControl instead of an AnalogOnScreenControl.

Comment: I wanted a horizontal analog controller, cause digital have only 2 positions. The answer was to make HorizontalAnalogScreenController from BaseController and AnalogController: super.onUpdateControlKnob(pRelativeX, 0);